# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setHost'

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material package in my angular application. I get the error

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setHost'
at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js:22:466)
at r.prototype.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:132:59)
at r.prototype.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:76)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:87:442)
at T (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:92:50)
at w.onload (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:93:78)
```

I can't understand the issue and hence can't find any way to resolve this. Although the functionalities of application are working fine except this error keeps coming.

Sharing head tag of my index.html below:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Resource Allocation Tool</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
```

Comment: in which browser you are getting this issue? Is it IE?

Comment: i think this is fix on the latest versions. have you tried using angular 1.6.x and latest version route, etc

Comment: @Thinker : This is issue comes in both IE and chrome

Comment: @kiro112: when I try to move to move to angular 1.6.4 version I get following error
        [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24HashMapProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24HashMap%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I was using version 1.4.8 of angular and 1.5.5 of angular-animate, making the version of angular and angular-animate same as 1.4.8 worked.